# Understanding Yahoo! Security Warnings

Tags: security, yahoo-mail

For the past couple of days I have been receiving emails from Yahoo! claiming they have stopped unauthorised access to my account.

> Someone attempted to sign in to your Yahoo! account from an app that doesn't meet Yahoo's security standards. We blocked this sign-in attempt, which was made on:
>
> Tue, 7 Jun 2016 21:39 BST from United Kingdom.

My issue is that Yahoo! do not provide any information beyond that. The access block is confusing as I am using my devices at the time of the alleged block and none of them have complained about being not able to connect.

My devices are:

- Windows 10 PC using Firefox
- Nexus 7 using the Yahoo! Mail app
- Moto G using the Yahoo! Mail app

Is there any way to find out the IP address and/or user-agent string of the blocked access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that these warnings are being generated from my chat/IM client (Trillian) as Yahoo are in the process of relaunching Yahoo Instant Messenger.

I only discovered this when I installed the Trillian app on my mobile. I got a security warning immediately when Trillian launched for the first time.

Answer (score 3):

If you are concerned then be sure to change your password as the first step.

There isn't much readily available information to find out what you want to know. However, log into your Yahoo! account and go to your "Account Information" page from the top right (below your name).

You should be asked for your password again. When the page opens, click on the link "View your recent sign-in activity" under Sign-In and Security section.

A new page will open where you can view the details of signing 'time', 'date', 'location' and 'type of login'. Location would be some indicator of an issue. You can contact the Customer Care on the same page.